# How can I match an exact tag using the nom library in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, parser-combinators, nom

I'm working on a tiny duration parsing library written in Rust, and using the nom library. In this library, I define a `second` parser combinator function. Its responsibility is to parse the various acceptable formats for representing seconds in a textual format.

```
    pub fn duration(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, std::time::Duration> {
       // Some code combining the various time format combinators
       // to match the format "10 days, 8 hours, 7 minutes and 6 seconds"  
    }

    pub fn seconds(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, u64> {
        terminated(unsigned_integer_64, preceded(multispace0, second))(input)
    }

    fn second(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
        alt((
            tag("seconds"),
            tag("second"),
            tag("secs"),
            tag("sec"),
            tag("s"),
        ))(input)
    }
```

So far, the tag combinator was behaving as I expected. However, I discovered recently that the following example fails, and is by definition failing:

```
assert!(second("se").is_err())
```

Indeed, the documentation states that "The input data will be compared to the tag combinator’s argument and will return the part of the input that matches the argument".

However, as my example hopefully illustrates, what I would like to achieve is for some flavor of tag that would fail if the whole input could not be parsed. I looked into explicitly checking if there is a rest after parsing the input; and found that it would work. Also, unsuccessfully explored using some flavors of the `complete` and `take` combinators to achieve that.

What would be an idiomatic way to parse an "exact match" of a word, and fail on a partial result (that would return a rest)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [all consuming](https://docs.rs/nom/6.2.1/nom/combinator/fn.all_consuming.html) combinator, which succeeds if the whole input has been consumed by its child parser:

```
// nom 6.1.2
use nom::branch::alt;
use nom::bytes::complete::tag;
use nom::combinator::all_consuming;
use nom::IResult;

fn main() {
    assert!(second("se").is_err());
}

fn second(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    all_consuming(alt((
        tag("seconds"),
        tag("second"),
        tag("secs"),
        tag("sec"),
        tag("s"),
    )))(input)
}
```

#### Update

I think I misunderstood your original question. Maybe this is closer to what you need. The key is that you should write smaller parsers, and then combine them:

```
use nom::branch::alt;
use nom::bytes::complete::tag;
use nom::character::complete::digit1;
use nom::combinator::all_consuming;
use nom::sequence::{terminated, tuple};
use nom::IResult;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Time {
    min: u32,
    sec: u32,
}

fn main() {
    //OK
    let parsed = time("10 minutes, 5 seconds");
    println!("{:?}", parsed);

    //OK
    let parsed = time("10 mins, 5 s");
    println!("{:?}", parsed);

    //Error -> although `min` is a valid tag, it would expect `, ` afterwards, instead of `ts`
    let parsed = time("10 mints, 5 s");
    println!("{:?}", parsed);

    //Error -> there must not be anything left after "5 s"
    let parsed = time("10 mins, 5 s, ");
    println!("{:?}", parsed);

    // Error -> although it starts with `sec` which is a valid tag, it will fail, because it would expect EOF
    let parsed = time("10 min, 5 sections");
    println!("{:?}", parsed);
}

fn time(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Time> {
    // parse the minutes section and **expect** a delimiter, because there **must** be another section afterwards
    let (rem, min) = terminated(minutes_section, delimiter)(input)?;

    // parse the minutes section and **expect** EOF - i.e. there should not be any input left to parse
    let (rem, sec) = all_consuming(seconds_section)(rem)?;

    // rem should be empty slice
    IResult::Ok((rem, Time { min, sec }))
}

// This function combines several parsers to parse the minutes section:
// NUMBER[sep]TAG-MINUTES
fn minutes_section(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, u32> {
    let (rem, (min, _sep, _tag)) = tuple((number, separator, minutes))(input)?;

    IResult::Ok((rem, min))
}

// This function combines several parsers to parse the seconds section:
// NUMBER[sep]TAG-SECONDS
fn seconds_section(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, u32> {
    let (rem, (sec, _sep, _tag)) = tuple((number, separator, seconds))(input)?;

    IResult::Ok((rem, sec))
}

fn number(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, u32> {
    digit1(input).map(|(remaining, number)| {
        // it can panic if the string represents a number
        // that does not fit into u32
        let n = number.parse().unwrap();
        (remaining, n)
    })
}

fn minutes(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    alt((
        tag("minutes"),
        tag("minute"),
        tag("mins"),
        tag("min"),
        tag("m"),
    ))(input)
}

fn seconds(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    alt((
        tag("seconds"),
        tag("second"),
        tag("secs"),
        tag("sec"),
        tag("s"),
    ))(input)
}

// This function parses the separator between the number and the tag:
//N<separator>tag -> 5[sep]minutes
fn separator(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    tag(" ")(input)
}

// This function parses the delimiter between the sections:
// X minutes<delimiter>Y seconds -> 1 min[delimiter]2 sec
fn delimiter(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    tag(", ")(input)
}
```

Here I have created a set of basic parsers for the building blocks, such as "number", "separator", "delimiter", the various markers (min, sec, etc). None of those expect to be "whole words". Instead you should use combinators, such as `terminated`, `tuple`, `all_consuming` to mark where the "exact word" ends.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for. I had used `all_consuming` before, but didn't think to use it in this context. Thank you very much!

Comment: Of course the `all_consuming` combinator should only be applied to the complete parser as it won't sequence with additional parsers any more.

Comment: I've hit this problem indeed just now. As I wrote a `duration` parser intended to parse in the `N years, M months, and X seconds`, each parser using the `all_consuming` combinator raises indeed an `EOF` error, as I would expect based on your comment. Do you have an alternative in mind that would help avoid that behavior?

Comment: @Oleiade as far as I understood you **expected** EOF. But if that's not the case, may you give a more complete example of the input data ? What is expected after `s`, `sec`, etc ?

Comment: The big picture is that I want to end up with a `duration` function that takes input in the form of `N years, M months, X seconds and Z microseconds` for instance. The `duration` function relies on "smaller" combinators with a smaller scope, such as `seconds` which parses a `multispace0` separated u64 and the result of `second`, a combinator that parses the words for seconds in textual format. The challenge is that `8 minutes, 6 seconds` should be valid, but not `8 minutes, 6 se` (I would like an invalid second format to make the `duration` parser fail. Does that help clarify?

Comment: I think my second example addresses that. You just have to tell the parser what to expect after the `tag()` - you can use `tuple()`, `terminated()`, `all_consuming()`, etc to do that.

Comment: I see, yes, you address it in the larger context. It does make a lot of sense! I'm going to go with this approach, thanks a lot for your support :)